# connecting greenplum database to python : JVMNotFoundError

Tags: python, database, greenplum

I am trying to connect greenplum database to python
But I am getting JVMNotFound Error

here is what I tried :

```
import jaydebeapi as jay

db_uid = "ABC"
db_pwd = "12345678"
jdbc_driver_name = "com.pivotal.jdbc.GreenplumDriver"
import os
jdbc_driver_loc = os.path.join('C:\Apps\Driver\greenlum.jar')




conn_string = jay.connect(jdbc_driver_name, 
'jdbc:pivotal:greenplum://xyz.com:5432;DatabaseName=abcd',
                      {'user': db_uid, 'password': db_pwd},
                      jars=jdbc_driver_loc)

 curs = conn.cursor()
 curs.execute("select * from alpha.beta limit(10)")
  result = curs.fetchall()
```

Error message : raise JVMNotFoundException("No JVM shared library file ({0}) "
jpype._jvmfinder.JVMNotFoundException: No JVM shared library file (jvm.dll) found. Try setting up the JAVA_HOME environment variable properly

any help is appreciated
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The error indicates that the Python `jaydebeapi` cannot locate a Java Runtime Environment (JRE) or Java Development Kit (JDK). If your system (the one you are running the Python code on) does not have Java installed, you will need to install it. If it does have it installed, you will need to set the JAVA_HOME environment variable to point at the install location.